# c# Serialize object without his property name

Tags: c#, html, serialization, properties, markup

Let's say I have an object having a single unique property : Value

```
[Serializable]
public class foo
{
    public string Value { get; set;}
}
```

This will be serialized this way :

```
<Foo>
<Value>
example
</Value>
</Foo>
```

Since it has only one property I would like the class to be serialized without the Value markup level :

```
<Foo>
example
</Foo>
```

How could I achieve this ?

Comment: What if you want to add a property to foo later?  How do you de-serialize into the new version of the object when the properties to deserialize to ambiguous?  I'd recommend not using foo at all, and any property previously using it should become a string instead.

Comment: Foo has other properties but the Value string is used as a single unique identifier for the object. The serialized version of this object is gonna be used by other users through messages and the users always forget the Value markup level. That's why I would prefer a serialized version of Foo without this markup level...